# Want to crop video in 1:1 aspectration using ffmpeg but it gives error Working Directory: null Environment: null

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I have used below command for crop video from originally captured by default camera. But when i was execute command it gives below error.

```
 final String[] cmd={"-i", "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/ZyfVideo/VID_20170914_153804.mp4","-s", "480x480" ,"-vf" ,"crop=480:480","setdar=1:1","setsar=1:1 ","/storage/emulated/0/Movies/SpoofApp/VDO_20170914_153811.mp4"};
```

**Error Logcat :**

```
09-14 15:38:11.874 3872-4039/com.spoof.app E/FFmpeg: Exception while trying to run: [Ljava.lang.String;@427ce088
                                                     java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [/data/data/com.spoof.app/files/ffmpeg, -i, /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/ZyfVideo/VID_20170914_153804.mp4, -s, 480x480, -vf, crop=480:480, setdar=1:1, setsar=1:1 , /storage/emulated/0/Movies/SpoofApp/VDO_20170914_153811.mp4] Working Directory: null Environment: null
                                                         at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:211)
                                                         at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:173)
                                                         at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:128)
                                                         at com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.ShellCommand.run(ShellCommand.java:10)
                                                         at com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.FFmpegExecuteAsyncTask.doInBackground(FFmpegExecuteAsyncTask.java:38)
                                                         at com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.FFmpegExecuteAsyncTask.doInBackground(FFmpegExecuteAsyncTask.java:10)
                                                         at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
                                                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                         at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
                                                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
                                                      Caused by: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
                                                         at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(Native Method)
                                                         at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:209)
                                                         at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:173) 
                                                         at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:128) 
                                                         at com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.ShellCommand.run(ShellCommand.java:10) 
                                                         at com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.FFmpegExecuteAsyncTask.doInBackground(FFmpegExecuteAsyncTask.java:38) 
                                                         at com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.FFmpegExecuteAsyncTask.doInBackground(FFmpegExecuteAsyncTask.java:10) 
                                                         at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288) 
                                                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
                                                         at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
                                                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                                                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
                                                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: Check you path correctly. Error stating that   Caused by: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory

Comment: @KingofMasses path for input video and output video ? But it is correct.

Comment: @KingofMasses Version 4.4.2 samsung tab

Comment: Then it might be some other.  Doi you have write permission in your app. because it is trying to write the op file in this location "/storage/emulated/0/Movies/SpoofApp/VDO_20170914_153811.mp4

Comment: @KingofMasses I have solved that issue but now after success output video folder empty how ?

Answer (score 0):

I have no such idea about ffmpeg but i can tell you about jCodec lib which is easy to use.

visit jcodec.org.

if you want to crop the video you will have to do below step in android or java.
1. get the frame from utility method from jcodec.
2. crop using Bitmap helper class. 
3. pack in the mp4 format using jcodec utilty function.

if you are not able to do this kindly write a mail to me sunilgupta3443@gmail.com

I will help to make the crop video application for you in android.

Thank you